# Multiple Prototypes inside constructor functions

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I have been researching this for hours. I wanted to find where the predefined method call() resides.
After creating a constructor function,

```
function computer() {
this.name = "my computer";
}
```

And after I `console.log(computer.prototype)` I find a constructor property and a prototype property.

[image]

The method `call()` is not defined inside this prototype, neither is it defined inside the prototype of its prototype.
But I see there is a constructor property and as the documentation says, it hold a reference to the function itself.
This allows me to look inside the computer constructor function (as this contructor property holds a reference to it). [image]

I can see that there are in fact *two* prototypes inside the computer constructor function, the first one has apparently the same properties as the prototype I am accessing this constructor from.

And the second one, (which is of type function *by spec*) has finally the method `call()` on it and it follows the proper prototypal chain as well. (inherting from function and function then inherting from object)

My first question is, how are there two prototypes inside the computer constructor function? We can have more than one prototype!? This first prototype seems to be only an object that has a constructor property that points to the function itself and its prototype pointing to `Object`. It doesn't even have all the methods like `call()` and `bind()` etc. So what is even its purpose?

Secondly, why am I not getting the second prototype when I use `computer.prototype` which seems to be actually following the prototype chain and has all the necessary methods in it.

Comment: The OP might e.g. read about [_"Inheritance and the prototype chain"_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) on MDN.

Answer (score 0):

> My first question is, how are there two prototypes inside the computer constructor function? We can have more than one prototype!?

No

> Secondly, why am I not getting the second prototype when I use computer.prototype

Function itself is an instance of "Function" object. Yes you can create function like this `const foo = new Function('return 1');` but you should not do this by different reasons including security problems. So if you look inside "Function" prototype you will find `call` and other methods which would be inherited by every instance of "Function". `computer.prototype.constructor` is a reference on `computer` function itself. `computer.prototype.constructor[[Prototype]]` is a reference on `Function.prototype`. `computer.prototype` is an instance of "Object" so `computer.prototype[[Prototype]]` is a reference on "Object.prototype". You can get access to `[[Prototype]]` by `__proto__` property.

```js
console.log(
  computer.prototype.__proto__ === Object.prototype,
  computer.prototype.constructor === computer,
  computer.prototype.constructor.__proto__ === Function.prototype,
  computer.__proto__ === Function.prototype
)
```